# Cannot install texlive-full or texlive-xetex under 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, texlive

I purged all traces of previous versions of texlive after doing the upgrade to 18.04, but I cannot now install texlive, texlive-full, or texlive-xetex.

For example, `sudo apt install texlive` gives me the message:

```
 Package texlive is not available, but is referred to by another package.
 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
 is only available from another source
 E: Package 'texlive' has no installation candidate
```

Likewise `sudo apt-cache policy texlive` gives me

```
 texlive
    Installed: (none)
    Candidate: (none)
    Version table:
```

I can install texlive-base, but I need texlive-xetex

Comment: This is strange. I have Ubuntu 18.04 and installed texlive-xetex. There is information that package exists https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/texlive-xetex. I have version 2017.20180305-1. I can find no information that it is not available for 18.04. The same applies for texlive and texlive-full. I have all of them installed.

Comment: What does **apt show texlive** show you? Can you post the output? I've installed texlive on ubuntu 18.04 without any problems too.

Comment: Do you have *universe* repository enabled (run `sudo add-apt-repository universe` if unsure)?  Are you sure that `sudo apt-get update` ran successfully? Please add output of its errors and output of `apt-cache policy texlive texlive-full texlive-xetex` to the question.

Comment: Many thanks N0rbert! It's always the things you take for granted that catch you out! I had indeed failed to enable the universe; once i did that, everything ran just fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Follow these instructions did the trick for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install texlive-xetex
```

(thanks to [N0rbert](https://askubuntu.com/users/66509/n0rbert) for pointing out to enable the *universe* repository)